# EPPlus Problem Creating List Validation from Table on another spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, epplus

I've created a table on one worksheet (list of state names) and named the table "tblStates". Then, on a second worksheet, there is a column for State where I want list validation for those cells, in which each cell has a dropdown offering the state names from the "tblStates" table. So for the State column in the 2nd worksheet, I created a table named "tblGeoStates" and added list validation to the column that references "=tblStates". (I referenced this article/video, although I don't have a 2nd dependent list, but just wanted to do the first part of this: [Contexture Video](https://www.contextures.com/exceldependentdropdown.html))

By following the steps from the link above, I've performed these steps manually in Excel and it works perfectly, however, when coding it via EPPlus, it doesn't work. The tables in each worksheet are present and named correctly. The list validation has been applied to the table in the 2nd worksheet and a dropdown appears on each cell in tblGeoStates. But there are no values being displayed.

**Worksheet 1 with tblStates table**
[image: Worksheet 1 with tblStates table]

**Worksheet 2 with tblGeoStates table with list validation that references the first table**
[image: Worksheet 2 with tblGeoStates table]

**When I try to click on the list validation dialog to close it, I receive this validation error from Excel - None of this happens in the manually created workbook and everything appears to be the same**

[image: Excel Validation Error]

**Code using EPPlus that generates each table and then the list validation on the 2nd table.**

```
        // Add Named Table for States column so we can reference it in another sheet
        using (ExcelRange r = ws.Cells[$"B6:B57"])
        {
            ExcelTableCollection tblcollection = ws.Tables;
            ExcelTable table = tblcollection.Add(r, "tblStates");                             
        }

        // Add Named Table for GeoStates column and validation that references tblStates
        using (ExcelRange r = ws.Cells["F:F"]) // also tried "F2:F1048576 so the header isn't included
        {
            ExcelTableCollection tblcollection = ws.Tables;
            ExcelTable table = tblcollection.Add(r, "tblGeoStates");
            table.ShowFilter = false;

            var v1 = r.DataValidation.AddListDataValidation();               
            v1.ShowErrorMessage = true;
            v1.ErrorStyle = ExcelDataValidationWarningStyle.warning;
            v1.ErrorTitle = "An invalid value was entered";
            v1.Error = "Select a value from the list";
            v1.Formula.ExcelFormula = "=tblStates"; // tried w & w/o = sign
        }
```

I've tried a few different things like including the header or not in the selected range for the tables; AllowedBlanks or not, showed filter or not, etc.

I've examined the underlying XML of both the manually created workbook as well as the one generated programmatically with EPPlus and they appear different.

**This is the EPPlus auto-generated one (doesn't work):**

```
<dataValidation sqref="F1:F1048576" errorStyle="warning" error="Select a value from the list" errorTitle="An invalid value was entered" showErrorMessage="1" type="list">
<formula1>tblStates</formula1>
</dataValidation>
```

**And this is the one I did manually (and works):**

```
<dataValidation xr:uid="{895EE9F3-E8D3-45B6-AD98-9A095C448064}" sqref="F1:F1048576" showErrorMessage="1" showInputMessage="1" type="list" allowBlank="1">
<formula1>tblStates</formula1>
</dataValidation>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use those tables? You can add the range directly.

```
using (ExcelRange r = worksheet.Cells["F:F"])
{
    var v1 = r.DataValidation.AddListDataValidation();
    v1.ShowErrorMessage = true;
    v1.ErrorStyle = ExcelDataValidationWarningStyle.warning;
    v1.ErrorTitle = "An invalid value was entered";
    v1.Error = "Select a value from the list";

    //reference the cells with the states directly
    v1.Formula.ExcelFormula = "B6:B57";

    //or if the data is in another sheet, you can reference that also
    v1.Formula.ExcelFormula = "'WorkSheet 2'!B:B";
}
```

Comment: Thank you @VDWWD.... I could certainly do that in this specific case since states are fairly static ;-) .  However I have 2 more cases in this same workbook where users can add rows to the referenced table, making the range undetermined upon initial creation of the workbook. So I was going by the linked tutorial (I referenced in my question above) and referencing a named table (since tables can grow dynamically), rather than a specific cell range. I've also tried an EPPlus "namedrange".

Comment: @razaross444, then in your case this answer is not very useful. Unfortunately I don't know how to reference tables in EPPlus either.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, but the problem was due to IExcelDataValidationList.Error value greater than 255 characters.