# How to fill data validation dropdown based of other sheet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, asp.net-core, openxml

I Have Two sheets and i want to add data validation to first column and fill its value based on first sheets first column.
this is my code:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument myDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(path, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = myDoc.AddWorkbookPart();
                workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

                Sheets sheets = myDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

                // the data for sheet 1
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart1 = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                Worksheet workSheet1 = new Worksheet();
                SheetData sheetData1 = new SheetData();

                workSheet1.AppendChild(sheetData1);
                worksheetPart1.Worksheet = workSheet1;

                Sheet sheet1 = new Sheet()
                {
                    Id = myDoc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart1),
                    SheetId = 1,
                    Name = "Sheet1"
                };
                sheets.Append(sheet1);


                // the data for sheet 2
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart2 = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                Worksheet workSheet2 = new Worksheet();
                SheetData sheetData2 = new SheetData();

                workSheet2.AppendChild(sheetData2);
                worksheetPart2.Worksheet = workSheet2;

                Sheet sheet2 = new Sheet()
                {
                    Id = myDoc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart2),
                    SheetId = 2,
                    Name = "Sheet2"
                };
                sheets.Append(sheet2);

                DataValidations dataValidations = new DataValidations();
                DataValidation dataValidation = new DataValidation()
                {
                    Type = DataValidationValues.List,
                    AllowBlank = true,
                    SequenceOfReferences = new ListValue<StringValue>() { InnerText = "A:A" }
                };
                Formula1 data = new Formula1();
                data.Text = $"\"=Sheet1!$A:$A\"";
                dataValidation.Append(data);
                dataValidations.Append(dataValidation);

                worksheetPart2.Worksheet.AppendChild(dataValidations);
            }
```

my problem is, when set data.TEXT equal **$""=Sheet1!$A:$A""**, it just show me a list with one row in dropdown.
**I want to get values in first column of sheet 1 and fill drop down in sheet2 based on it**

Comment: Not sure if you are using EPPlus. But in there you cannot add the validation range as a string. You have to use the Adresses. Maybe that's also the case here. And if you do use EPPlus, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53600471/epplus-problem-creating-list-validation-from-table-on-another-spreadsheet

Comment: i am using OpenXML @VDWWD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a small change your code worked for me.  Just remove the inner quotes.

```
data.Text = $"=Sheet1!$A:$A";
```

[image]

[image]